# The only supported ciphers - Laravel hosting on Fortrabbit

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, hosting, fortrabbit

This question is all over **stackoverflow** but I just had to post it again.
Mine is actually on **Fortrabbit**, I've been having this error on Fortrabbit for a Laravel 5.4 App, even after I've generated the key with `php artisan key:generate` and in my `config/app.php` I have `"cypher" : "AES-256-CBC"`.

Almost tried all it takes to fix this error, but still getting it at the end.

```
The only supported ciphers are AES-128-CBC and AES-256-CBC with the correct key lengths.
```

Is this a **Fortrabbit** thing? I don't know if anyone else has encoountered this on **Fortrabbit**
Any help is appreciated.

I've done `php artisan config:cache`, `composer install` still the same.

Thanks

Comment: When does this error occur? The config uses array values so it should be `'cipher' => 'AES-256-CBC',` in your app.php.

Comment: Yeah that's how it is. Just a mistake when I typed `'cipher' : 'AES-256-CBC'`

Comment: So when are you getting the error? While generating the key or while using the app like loading a page?

Comment: While loading the page on the browser. Key generation is successful

Comment: Can you share the app key that was generated?

Comment: Sure: `base64:l2rGEVzjnzGbqUjx/AKuy5UFA9mQScv5k1ctYuqE62Y=`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145610/discussion-between-sandeesh-and-michel).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After debugging and testing out, the issue is with how fortrabbit handles environment variables. Apparently it ignores the .env file and sets its own default values. Or you're using git deployment which has the .env file ignored by default. To set your own values, you need to update them in their dashboard.

https://help.fortrabbit.com/install-laravel-5-uni

Just copy all your .env file content and add them in the dashboard. As an alternative you can set the values in the configuration files.

Comment: That's correct, the .env file is gitignored - it's the laravel default and a good practice. APP_KEY needs to be updated under the ENV vars in the fortrabbit Dashboard.

Answer (score 0):

Along with `php artisan config:cache`
do

```
php artisan cache:clear
and php artisan config:clear
```

Hope that helps

Comment: Did all that some hours earlier. Actually just did it again, but still the same error. I don't know if this an issue with Fortrabbit server